# State change in R

Tags: r

I am trying to tag the change in state of different records month on month.

In my data-set, i have is structured as below:

[image]

For state change columns, it must be 0, if Paid(Y/N) flag changes from past month.

I have tried using grouping the data but with grouping i am getting only one entry consolidated for all months. However i want to keep every months entry of same record intact.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please read these guidelines on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/8675075 (you're much more likely to find the help you're looking for).

Comment: Hi Saurabh, welcome to stackoverflow. To have us correctly help you with your question, it is advised not to include images, but an example of your data. have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a dataframe that is alike to yours, for ease of explanation, try to provide a reproducible example yourself next time :-).

```
df <- data.frame( "id" = c(1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6), # id values
        "month" = c(6,7,8,9,6,7,8, 9,6,7,8,9), # month values
        "outstanding" = c(500, 300, 30, 40, 56, 32, 35, 40, 56, 32, 32, 59), #outstanding amount
        "paid" = c("n", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y","n", "y", "y", "n", "n", "y"), # paid yes or no
        "state" = '', #state: filling next
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE # not having characters as factors, not really needed here.
        )
```

This dataframe is grouped on id and than mutated by using the `lag`function from dplyr. This function compares, within your grouping, the current value with the value above. `lead` does the opposite.

```
df %>%
  group_by( id) %>% #group observations by their id
  mutate( state = ifelse( paid == lag(paid), "stable", "change")) # if the current observations, grouped by id, differs from the previous (lagged), we observe a change.
```

Note that for your data, it might be needed to transform your month of payment to an ordered factor or date, to correctly find a change in state

Comment: Thanks, it is working and will follow your suggestions.

Comment: Done, I am new to community so did not know this feature... Thanks again..